# Dallas Lock V7.7 - не взламывается?

Tags: защита, безопасность, пароль

Доброго всем здравия.
Почитал про СЗИ от НСД (средство защ.инф. от несанкционированного доступа) Dallas Lock V7.7.
От этого легче не стало...
Пароли на Windows, BIOS по сравнению с этим - семечки...
Главная проблема в том, что тот человек пропал, теперь с 10-ок ПК под этой штукой.
Я так понимаю выход радикальный только? Старый добрый format c:?
Или есть возможность привести в чувства это чудо СЗИ?Я так понимаю, через альтернативную ОС на винт всё равно не попасть?
Ведь сидит она явно на винте.
P.S.(over 10 ПК форматировать, натягивать Win + дрова дело не одного часа).

Answer (score 1):

> P.S.(over 10 ПК форматировать, натягивать Win + дрова дело не одного часа).

Упрощу Вам задачу... Делаете Acronis-ом ОДИН образ диска с установленной ось и дровами_на_всё, после чего просто разворачиваете его на целевые машины. SSD-to-SSD занимает примерно три-четыре минуты, HDD-to-HDD занимает от 10 до 20 минут.

Нужно:

- машина с "правильной" форточкой, дровами, софтом...... - для образа, бэкапить лучше на другой физический носитель
- машина (две, три... чем больше) с Acronis-ом - для развертывания бэкапов.

Это может быть одна и та же машина. Могут быть разные. Можно бэкапить/разворачивать с загрузочного диска.

После чего складываете винты горкой и разворачиваете. Если дров было достаточно - после подключения винта к целевой машине получаете готовую систему. Не забудьте после запуска целевых машин сменить ключик на тот, что на наклейке;)

Из опыта: таким вот манером офис на 31 машинку был развернут в течении дня. (DC, mail, etc - на следующий день)))

ЗЫ Ломать, мне кажется, не совсем гут...

Comment: to: @Zerglyn.  Ломать не гут?  А инфу убить всю на данных ПК, выходит гут?

Comment: Кстати, удаление Файловой систем не помогло.  Крепкая штука ;)  Видать в контроллер винта прописывается